# Duplicate Image Detector Not Deleting All Duplicate Files

Tags: python, computer-vision

I use a double for loop to iterate through the files in my Picture folder. If the first image is equal to the second image, I then delete the second image from the folder and delete the image from the list of files I'm iterating through. My program leaves some duplicate images and doesn't delete them, but when I run the program again it deletes the duplicate image. How to I properly iterate through my files so that I am able to delete all duplicate images?

I've tried cutting down on unnecessary if, else loops in order to make sure the file doesn't slip through the program.

```
path = "Pictures"
directory = os.listdir(path)

for first_file in directory:
    for second_file in directory:

        if first_file == second_file:
            continue

        if first_file.endswith(".jpg") and second_file.endswith(".jpg"):

            first_file_path = R"Pictures\{}".format(first_file)
            second_file_path = R"Pictures\{}".format(second_file)

            img1 = cv2.imread(first_file_path, 1)
            img2 = cv2.imread(second_file_path, 1)

            img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (100,100))
            img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (100,100))

            difference = cv2.subtract(img1, img2)
            b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)

            if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0:
                os.remove(second_file_path)
                directory.remove(second_file)
```

Comment: What is `first_file` or more specifically, what is the type of `directory` ? Is it a list of filenames ? I see you are resizing the images, perhaps that's why they get deleted during the second run.

Comment: I've edited the code to specify what the directory is and what is first_file. The directory is a list of files from the specified path. The first_file is the first file in directory that I'm iterating through. I'm trying to see whether there are duplicate files inside a specified directory, by using double for loop through the same list.

Comment: thank you ! I asked because when I was reading the question I thought you are comparing the outputs of `cv2.imread` using the `==` operator. As I'm looking at your code it makes sense so it *should* work. Is one of the pictures 1 pixel wider ? Maybe the second time you run the images get compared in reverse order which kinda makes sense.